# Mapping an array to int Java

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to map and array of ints to an int value. I know that int[] wont work as keys. I have tried List however that doesn't work as well. Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
    private void createMap(){
    List<Integer> state_action_pair = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<this.stateActionTable.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<this.stateActionTable[0].length;j++){
            state_action_pair.add(this.stateActionTable[i][j]);
        }
        this.stateActionMap.put(state_action_pair, i);
        state_action_pair.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: int[] can work as a key for a hashmap just fine. A List<Integer> on the otherhand doesn't. It isn't clear why you are trying to do, and why it fails. You also leave off the relevant information, what is stateActionMap?

Comment: @matt no. An int[] is only equal to itself. A List is equal to any other list containing equal elements in the same order.

Comment: @JBNizet exactly the point. A List, the .equals will change over time, making it unsuitable for a hashmap. An int[] will remain the same.

Comment: @matt It won't change over time if the list isn't mutated. The whole point is to be able to do `map.get(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))`. That is impossible to do with an array, because `new int[] {1, 2, 3}` won't ever be equal to the array used as key in the map.

Comment: It's not about array or list but about mutability. `HashMap`/`HashSet` docs both say that behaviour is undefined if the keys are modified. If the list is immutable, it can be safely used as a key.

Comment: @JBNizet does he want to be able to access the elements using the same values. Do you know that OP wants int[] a = {1,2,3} to access the same element as int[] b={1,2,3}? Of course "if the list isn't mutated" it doesn't change.

Comment: Well, I guess that's what the OP wants, since he said: "I know that int[] wont work as keys".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you use a single `ArrayList` instance for all the keys of your `Map`. You need an individual instance for each key :

```
private void createMap(){
  for(int i=0;i<this.stateActionTable.length;i++){
    List<Integer> state_action_pair = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j=0;j<this.stateActionTable[0].length;j++){
        state_action_pair.add(this.stateActionTable[i][j]);
    }
    this.stateActionMap.put(state_action_pair, i);
}
```

Comment: Note that using mutable data structures as keys in a map is typically a big no-no.

Comment: @aioobe As long as the OP doesn't mutate them, everything will work fine. Of course, using an immutable List would be safer.

Comment: Do i have to save all these instances or is it fine that they get deleted after the function returns? thanks

Comment: @Kenadams They are not deleted as long as the Map is not deleted, since the Map keeps references to them.

Comment: @Eran then why not prevent the list from being mutated, and use `Collections.unmodifiableList(state_action_pair)` as key?